# How can I recover software RAID 0 after formatting my primary OS drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, software-raid

I was previously running Windows 7 on a machine that had 5 physical drives - 1 was the primary drive the OS was installed on, and the other 4 were a RAID 0 that was created through Windows 7 disk management.

Last month I formatted the primary drive and installed Windows 8, and the 4 drives that were part of a RAID are now just unformatted disks when looking in Windows 8 disk management. Is there any way to rebuild the RAID without losing the files I had stored on it?

Answer (score 1):

I've had success with [Raid Reconstructor](http://www.runtime.org/raid.htm) (Paid) in the past, but if you've overwritten one drive out of 4 in a RAID0, I'd be surprised if you get much back. Worth a try though.

Also, do you have backups of your data? Running RAID0 without a backup is...brave.

Edit: My mistake, OS drive was wiped not data drives. Windows should pick up the striped array, but perhaps moving to Windows 8 means it won't. As above, Raid Reconstructor should be able to rebuild the array and pull data off.

Comment: I think he overwrite one disk **not** belonging to the RAID set. 5 drives. [1x OS_Drive], [4x disk for the stripe]. I agree that a 4 drive stripe is brave.

Comment: Correct, the 4 striped drives were left untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Go into Disk Management and you should see the drives/LUs listed as 'Foreign Disks', right-click where it shows the Disk number and you should see an option to 'Import Foreign Disks...'.  Follow the dialogs and you should be able to access the array in no time.