# How to recover RAID0 lost after a upgrade to Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, hard-drive, ssd, raid

[How can I recover software RAID 0 after formatting my primary OS drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/553130/how-can-i-recover-software-raid-0-after-formatting-my-primary-os-drive)

I had the same issue as this post :
I was previously running Windows 7 on a machine that had 4 physical drives and 1 SSD for the OS.The other 4 were a RAID 0 that was created through Windows 7 disk management.

Last month I upgraded to Windows 8, and the 4 drives that were part of a RAID are now just unformatted disks when looking in Windows 8 disk management. I tried to use Raid reconstructor as it is explain in the above post. It worked for 1 of the 2 RAID.

For the second RAID, the analyse of Raid Reconstructor failed to find the correct configuration so when I copy the data on another disk, I cannot open the .img like for the first RAID. None of the disks were formatted so the data should still be there but i cannot manage to access it.

NOTE: The folder Windows.old was deleted after the upgrade, so I cannot boot back to Windows 7. And no restauration point were create before the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things you really do not want to hear but it has to be said:

- ALWAYS have a fresh `BACKUP` of a Raid-0-Array
- you SHOULD `RECOVER`your data from a Backup

Well - you would not ask this questions if you had the ability to recover your data from a Backup.

So i need to mention the following uncommon facts too.

- NEVER try to recover a failed array on the original disks
- Make a real `1:1-Copy` with a Cloning Program of your Choice and try to recover your Data on the new cloned disks.
- if you "repaired" something and it did not work you probably made it WORSE

There are professional Data-Recovery-Services out there (like http://www.krollontrack.com) but you should take in mind that the recovery of a raid array may cost a few thousand EUR/USD.

Comment: Thank you for your advice :
- it's not my data I try to recover otherwise I would have a backup
- never use software RAID I know
- I did not make it worse, I use RAID reconstructor to clone the 2 RAID on another disk (I use to 2 spare HDD of 1 TB). I worked for 1 of the 2 RAID-0, not for the other one.

The purpose of this thread is to hope someone had a similar problem while i'm searching for a solution. Maybe someone that already use RAID reconstructor of maybe another software

Telling me that I should have a backup is not helping me :(